# Refactor C# code (help improve)

Tags: c#, refactoring

I need help to refactor some parts of this code example from where `if (_obj is Application)` so this will be generic.

```
public override void Body(object _obj, object _objInPreviousState)
        {

            if (_obj != null)
            {
                string Message = "";
                string Subject = "";
                if (_objInPreviousState == null)
                {
                    var emailParams = this.Param as Dictionary<string, string>;
                    if (emailParams != null)
                    {
                        Message = emailParams["Message"];
                        Subject = emailParams["Subject"];
                    }
                }
                var emails = userRepository().GetForRoles("RM").Select(c => c.Email);
                if (_obj is Application)
                {
                    var app = (Application)_obj;
                    var appInPreviousState = _objInPreviousState as Application;
                    if (appInPreviousState == null)
                    {
                        emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), Message, Subject);
                    }
                    else if (app.ApplicationStatus != appInPreviousState.ApplicationStatus)
                    {
                        emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), "Application: " + app.ID + " changed decision status: " + Enum.GetName(typeof(AppStatus), app.ApplicationStatus), "Check following application: " + app.ID);
                    }
                }
                else if (_obj is Product)
                {
                    var product = (Product)_obj;
                    var prodInPreviousState = _objInPreviousState as Product;
                    if (prodInPreviousState == null)
                    {
                        emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), Message, Subject);
                    }
                    else if (product.ProductStatusType != prodInPreviousState.ProductStatusType)
                    {
                        emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), "Product: " + product.ID + " for application " + product.ApplicationID + " changed decision status: " + Enum.GetName(typeof(AppStatus), product.ProductStatusType), "Check following application: " + product.ApplicationID);
                    }
                }

                else if (_obj is CES)
                {
                    var ces = (CES)_obj;
                    var cesInPreviousState = _objInPreviousState as CES;
                    if (cesInPreviousState == null)
                    {
                        emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), Message, Subject);
                    }
                    else if (ces.Status != cesInPreviousState.Status)
                    {
                        emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), "CES for application " + ces.ApplicationID + " changed decision status: " + Enum.GetName(typeof(CesStatuses), ces.Status), "Check following application: " + ces.ApplicationID);
                    }
                }
                else if (_obj is Comment)
                {
                    var comment = (Comment)_obj;
                    emailService().SendEmails("aps@somedomain.com", emails.ToArray(), "Comment for the following application: " + comment.ApplicationID + " with message: " + comment.Message + " on date: " + comment.CreatedDate, "Comment for the following application: " + comment.ApplicationID);
                }
                mLog.InfoLine("Sendet Email");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean generic as in `Generic<T>` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.80).aspx) or would just using an `interface` for polymorphism be fine?

Comment: basically look at the repeated items in your code and think of how you can make these reusable.    first thing I would do is change the if statements to a case statement and move all the downline processing in to a separate method.    You can also look at tools like coderush.

Comment: Maybe this question could be better placed in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use some interfaces, I've not given you the full code but a pattern to follow.

```
interface IStatusItem
{
   void SendEmails(EmailService service);
}

public class Product : IStatusItem
{
   public void SendEmails(EmailService service)
   {
      // Send Email
   }
}

public class Application : IStatusItem
{
   public void SendEmails(EmailService service)
   {
      // Send Email
   }
}
```

Then your main code doesn't need all the if blocks. It just calls through to the implementation on the instance of the IStatusItem. Obviously you need to add the previous state in there.

```
override void Body(object _obj, object _objInPreviousState)
{
   IStatusItem sItem = obj as IStatusItem;
   if(sItem != null)
      sItem.SendEmails(emailService());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things you can easily improve:

First, invert some of the `if`s to reduce nesting. In particular:

```
if (_obj != null) { ... the entire function ... }
```

Can be

```
if (null == _obj) { return; }
... the rest ...
```

Also, extract each of the if/else bodies into separate methods (you can simply select the body and choose Refactor...Extract Method from the menu.

Lastly, you should be able to generalize all those methods into a single one that takes a few more parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can make a factory that produces objects.

This is how i would refactor:

SomethingFactory produces AbstractSomething derived classes(ConcreteSomethingA, ConcreteSomethingB etc). The Factory produces the ConcreteSomethings depending on the "_obj" and

```
public override void Body(object _obj, object _objInPreviousState)
```

would be implemented in the concrete classes thus the system could be easely extended

Answer (score 1):

1. Inverse _obj into `if ( _obj == null ) return;`
2. Replace `""` declarations into `string.Empty`
3. Use string.Format to format strings with a lot of concatenations
4. extract email address to configuration file
5. Create item's interface

   ```
   public interface IEmail{
     string GetMessage();
     string GetSubject();
   }
   ```
6. Create factory to generate `IEmail` instances
7. Send email in a single call

   ```
    public void Body(object obj, object objInPreviousState)
       {
         const string Address= "aps@somedomain.com"; //extract to configuration
         IEmail item = GetEmailItem(_obj, _objInPreviousState);
         if(item != null) emailService().SendEmails( Address, emails.ToArray(), item.GetMessage(), item.GetSubject() );
       }
   ```